# How to add hover effect for each slice (html5 canvas)

Tags: html, canvas, charts, pie-chart

hi can u help me to setup this code. I m not so good at html5.

> This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     // initialize some variables for the chart
>     var 
>
> canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
>         var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
>         var data = [75,68,32,95,20,51];
>         var colors = ["#7E3817", "#C35817", "#EE9A4D", "#A0C544", "#348017", "#307D7E"];
>         var center = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2];
>         var radius = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / 2;
>         var lastPosition = 0, total = 0;
>         var pieData = [];
>
>     // total up all the data for chart
>     for (var i in data) { total += data[i]; }
>
>     // populate arrays for each slice
>     for(var i in data) {
>         pieData[i] = [];
>         pieData[i]['value'] = data[i];
>         pieData[i]['krasa'] = colors[i];
>         pieData[i]['startAngle'] = 2 * Math.PI * lastPosition;
>         pieData[i]['endAngle'] = 2 * Math.PI * (lastPosition + (data[i]/total));
>         lastPosition += data[i]/total;
>     }
>
> function drawChart()
>     {
>         for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
>         {
>             var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
>             gradient.addColorStop( 0, "#ddd" );
>             gradient.addColorStop( 1, colors[i] );
>             ctx.beginPath();
>             ctx.moveTo(center[0],center[1]);
>             ctx.arc(center[0],center[1],radius,pieData[i]['startAngle'],pieData[i]['endAngle'],false);
>             ctx.lineTo(center[0],center[1]);
>             ctx.closePath();
>             ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
>             ctx.fill();
>             ctx.lineWidth = 1;
>             ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
>             ctx.stroke();
>         }
>     }
>
>     drawChart(); // first render
> });
> ```

How to add **hover** effect for *each slice*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have drawn your wedges to the canvas, they become just pixels in a larger image.

You have no way to track the individual pie wedges at this point.  Therefore no way to track hovers on any particular wedge.

But...You do have several options!

Option#1 --- Make your own hit-test to determine which pie wedge you clicked on.

It would look something like this (I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS !!!)

```
var chartStartAngle=0;  // you started drawing the pie at angle 0

function handleChartClick ( clickEvent ) {

    // Get the mouse cursor position at the time of the click, relative to the canvas
    var mouseX = clickEvent.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = clickEvent.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    // Was the click inside the pie chart?
    var xFromCenter = mouseX - center[0];
    var yFromCenter = mouseY - center[1];
    var distanceFromCenter = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( Math.abs( xFromCenter ), 2 ) + Math.pow( Math.abs( yFromCenter ), 2 ) );

    if ( distanceFromCenter <= radius ) {

      // You clicked inside the chart.
      // So get the click angle 
      var clickAngle = Math.atan2( yFromCenter, xFromCenter ) - chartStartAngle;

      if ( clickAngle < 0 ) clickAngle = 2 * Math.PI + clickAngle;

      for ( var i in pieData ) {
        if ( clickAngle >= pieData[i]['startAngle'] && clickAngle <= pieData[i]['endAngle'] ) {
          // You clicked on pieData[i]
          // So do your effect here!
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Option#2 --- Use a cavas library which allows you to keep track of each wedge in your pie chart and therefore do your hover effect.  Several good libraries (among many good ones) are: EaselJs, FabricJs and KineticJs.

Elated.com has a great tutorial that shows what you're looking for. Check it out: http://www.elated.com/articles/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/